# How to get the size of children widget when the `build` method are called in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a view which include an scroll animation are called `BubbleTabBar`. Have a list of children widget inside my `BubbleTabBar`. I want to detect the size of all children inside `BubbleTabBar` for enable/disable scroll. However, I only get the parent size by `LayoutBuilder`. Now, I have to force user input only list of text to my widget and calculate the size by `RenderParagraph`. **I wonder that have any way to calculate the size of widget at build time**? Use global key to get render instance are not working for me.

**TL;DR**:

> I wonder that have any way to calculate the size of widget at build time?

Demo source code here (Please change the size of preview panel):

> https://dartpad.dev/embed-flutter.html?theme=dark&id=6f6a5fc73803bdfaf2a493a35c258fee

Comment: That's impossible. Use Renderobjects instead

Comment: Thank you for your answer. :/ That's so hard to make a dynamic widget there. :D

Comment: That's hard because that's not the role of widgets. Widgets are purposefully unaware of layout informations, including size and position.  That's what RenderObjects are here for. If you're having difficult time understanding them, try [CustomMultiChildLayout](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomMultiChildLayout-class.html) first, which is a simplification of RenderObjects